# [Vue warn]: Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The following code has been written to handle an event after a button click

```
var MainTable = Vue.extend({
  template: "<ul>" +
    "<li v-for='(set,index) in settings'>" +
    "{{index}}) " +
    "{{set.title}}" +
    "<button @click='changeSetting(index)'> Info </button>" +
    "</li>" +
    "</ul>",
  data: function() {
    return data;
  }
});

Vue.component("main-table", MainTable);

data.settingsSelected = {};
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#settings",
  data: data,
  methods: {
    changeSetting: function(index) {
      data.settingsSelected = data.settings[index];
    }
  }
});
```

But the following error occurred:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "changeSetting" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in `<MainTable>`)

Comment: Your component does not have access to methods defined on your Vue. You need to add the method `changeSetting` to the `MainTable` component.

Comment: Note: If you get this error with `<nuxt-link v-if='computedProperty' />`. Try moving the reference outside of <nuxt-link>.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

## Problem

> `[Vue warn]: Property or method "changeSetting" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in <MainTable>)`

The error is occurring because the `changeSetting` method is being referenced in the `MainTable` component here:

```
    "<button @click='changeSetting(index)'> Info </button>" +
```

However the `changeSetting` method is not defined in the `MainTable` component. It is being defined in the root component here:

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#settings",
  data: data,
  methods: {
    changeSetting: function(index) {
      data.settingsSelected = data.settings[index];
    }
  }
});
```

What needs to be remembered is that properties and methods can only be referenced in the scope where they are defined.

> **Everything in the parent template is compiled in parent scope; everything in the child template is compiled in child scope.**

You can read more about component compilation scope in Vue's [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Compilation-Scope).

## What can I do about it?

So far there has been a lot of talk about defining things in the correct scope so the fix is just to move the `changeSetting` definition into the `MainTable` component?

It seems that simple but here's what I recommend.

You'd probably want your `MainTable` component to be a dumb/presentational component. ([Here](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0) is something to read if you don't know what it is but a tl;dr is that the component is just responsible for rendering something – no logic). The smart/container element is responsible for the logic – in the example given in your question the root component would be the smart/container component. With this architecture you can use Vue's parent-child communication methods for the components to interact. You pass down the data for `MainTable` via [props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props) and emit user actions from `MainTable` to its parent via [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events). It might look something like this:

```
Vue.component('main-table', {
  template: "<ul>" +
    "<li v-for='(set, index) in settings'>" +
    "{{index}}) " +
    "{{set.title}}" +
    "<button @click='changeSetting(index)'> Info </button>" +
    "</li>" +
    "</ul>",
  props: ['settings'],
  methods: {
    changeSetting(value) {
      this.$emit('change', value);
    },
  },
});


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#settings',
  template: '<main-table :settings="data.settings" @change="changeSetting"></main-table>',
  data: data,
  methods: {
    changeSetting(value) {
      // Handle changeSetting
    },
  },
}),
```

The above should be enough to give you a good idea of what to do and kickstart resolving your issue.

Comment: Is this the most preferred approach currently? Things keep evolving a lot in Vue so I though I would ask

Comment: I'm no expert in Vue, but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43292810/how-to-call-a-method-in-vue-app-from-the-vue-component suggests you can call app's function from your component via `$root`. E.g. `this.$root.changeSetting(value)` directly from component's `changeSetting(..)` in this case.
Looks more convenient to me...

Comment: @Aseem: separating concerns of code to make things easier to understand and change is timeless. The method described in the answer separates the concern of data and the concern of presenting that data and is just one example of how things might be done. I would not evaluate the approach as to if it is 'current' but whether it makes code easier to change and understand.

Comment: @FlasHfromRu: You can reference things from `$root` but in general it is not a good idea. See this note on accessing root instances from Vue's [documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance): "This can be convenient for demos or very small apps with a handful of components. However, the pattern does not scale well to medium or large-scale applications, so we strongly recommend using [Vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) to manage state in most cases."

Answer (score 61):

Should anybody land with the same silly problem I had, make sure your component has the '**data**' property spelled correctly. (eg. *data*, and not *date*)

```html
<template>
  <span>{{name}}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
name: "MyComponent",
data() {
  return {
    name: ""
  };
}
</script>
```

Comment: Me here in 2020, I wrote DATE

Comment: lmfao this comment just saved me

Comment: It throws the same error when you misspell your property names. For me it happened because I used plural `datas` in the template.

Comment: `Should anybody land with the same silly problem I had, make sure your component has the 'data' property spelled correctly.` Lol really a very siilly problem :) thanks man

Comment: This comment saved me! I had "computed" defined within with the "data" property.

Comment: bruh I wrote date

Comment: Same problem here. I wrote `properties` instead of `props`. Beware of the misspellings, friends, Vue doesn't seem to warn about not used properties in the configuration object.

Comment: January 13 2022 and your post saved me!

Comment: Vue would be do much better without all of these gotchas...

Comment: wow, I never thought I could do such silly mistake.

Comment: yes, VUE should definitely be more specific with its errors. It's sometimes the biggest time consumer to interpret WHAT PRECISELY it meant by some generic error

Comment: Hence why people should use Vue code snippets rather than writing it by hand: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sdras.vue-vscode-snippets

Answer (score 39):

In my case the reason was, I only forgot the closing

```
</script>
```

tag.

But that caused the same error message.

Comment: Dude... that was it! I would have never found this.

Comment: Unexpected, my some hours error is this one :)

Comment: Thank you. I looked all over before finding this solution.

Comment: Already lost 15 mins on this, and I have no idea how much more time you just saved me!

Comment: two hours for me on this one... thanks mate I thought I was losing my mind lmao

Comment: This was me too... In fact it was just the last '>' I'd missed ‍♂️

Answer (score 15):

If you're experiencing this problem, check to make sure you don't have

```
methods: {
...
}
```

or

```
computed: {
...
}
```

declared twice

Comment: Holy moly! I got this and I didn't know it

Comment: thank you! I've been freaking out on this!

Comment: Typo'ing `method` is a classic one too.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably caused by spelling error

I got a typo at script closing tag

```
</sscript>
```

Comment: This or bad naming convention: I had the error trying to call `fileList` but the data property was `filelist`.

Answer (score 8):

**Remember to return the property**

Another reason of seeing the *Property "search" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance* is when you forget to return the variable in the `setup(){}` function

So remember to add the return statement at the end:

```
export default {

  setup(){

    const search = ref('')
    //Whatever code

    return {search}

  }
}
```

Note: I'm using the Composition API

Answer (score 5):

Adding my bit as well, should anybody struggle like me, notice that *methods* is a case-sensitive word:

```
<template>
    <span>{{name}}</span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  Methods: {
      name() {return '';}
  }
</script>
```

'Methods' should be 'methods'

Comment: in my case, I had method LOL

Comment: Same here, I had "method" instead of "methods". It would be good if Vue or linters can pick this up at compile time.

Answer (score 4):

If you use two times vue instance. Then it will give you this error. For example in **app.js** and your own script tag in view file. Just use one time

```
 const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I got this error when I tried assigning a component property to a state property during instantiation

```
export default {
 props: ['value1'],
 data() {
  return {
   value2: this.value1 // throws the error
   }
  }, 
 created(){
  this.value2 = this.value1 // safe
 }
}
```

Comment: if you don't have any typo this is the best anwer!

Answer (score 4):

My issue was I was placing the methods inside my data object. just format it like this and it'll work nicely.

```
<script>
module.exports = {
    data: () => {
        return {
            name: ""
        }
    },
    methods: {
        myFunc() {
            // code
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I wrote it as "method" instead of "methods". So stupid. Wasted around 1 hour.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This was driving me insane.

Comment: I wrote date() instead of data()

Answer (score 3):

## Some common cases of this error

- Make sure your component has the **data** property spelled correctly
- Make sure your template is bot defined within another component’s template.
- Make sure you defined the variable inside data object
- Make sure your router name in string

[Get some more sollution](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-during-render-make-sure-to-declare-reactive-data-properties-in-the-data-option/19715)

Comment: Nice summary! Also double check the function name matches:
 :class="boxAClasses"         vs       boxAclasses() { … }

Comment: "Make sure your template is bot defined within" ... did you mean "NOT defined within"?

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a spelling error of reserved vuejs variables. I got here because I misspelled `computed:` and vuejs would not recognize my computed property variables. So if you have an error like this, check your spelling first!

Answer (score 2):

I had two `methods:` in the `<script>`, goes to show, that you can spend hours looking for something that was such a simple mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the Vue3 `<script setup>` style, make sure you've actually specified `setup` in the opening script tag:

```
<script setup>
```

I had lapsed into old habits and only created a block with `<script>`, but it took a while to notice it.

https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html

Answer (score 2):

if you have any props or imported variables (from external .js file) make sure to set them properly using created like this;

make sure to init those vars:

```
import { var1, var2} from './constants'

//or

export default {
     data(){
      return {
       var1: 0,
       var2: 0,
       var3: 0,
      },
    },
    props: ['var3'],
    created(){
     this.var1 = var1;
     this.var2 = var2;
     this.var3 = var3;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a property that gave me the error, the correct writing and still gave me the error in the console. I searched so much and nothing worked for me, until I gave him Ctrl + F5 and Voilá! error was removed. :'v

Answer (score 1):

Look twice the warning : *Property _____ was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.*
So you have to define it ... in the data function for example which commonly instantiate variables in a Vuejs app. and,  it was my case and that way the problem has been fixed.
That's all folk's !

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to add the `return` keyword:

```
computed: {
    image(){
        this.productVariants[this.selectedVariant].image;
    },
    inStock(){
       this.productVariants[this.selectedVariant].quantity;
    }
}
```

Change to:

```
computed: {
    image(){
        return this.productVariants[this.selectedVariant].image;
    },
    inStock(){
       return this.productVariants[this.selectedVariant].quantity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was the methods: `{ }` I had put the `}` before my method functions so for example I had it like this methods: `{ function , function }, function, function` so some of the functions that were out of the curly braces were not included inside the methods function.

Answer (score 0):

Although some answers here maybe great, none helped my case (which is very similar to OP's error message).

This error needed fixing because even though my components rendered with their data (pulled from API), when deployed to firebase hosting, it did not render some of my components (the components that rely on data).

To fix it (and given you followed the suggestions in the accepted answer), in the Parent component (the ones pulling data and passing to child component), I did:

```
// pulled data in this life cycle hook, saving it to my store
created() {
  FetchData.getProfile()
    .then(myProfile => {
      const mp = myProfile.data;
      console.log(mp)
      this.$store.dispatch('dispatchMyProfile', mp)
      this.propsToPass = mp;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('There was an error:', error.response)
    })
}
// called my store here
computed: {
    menu() {
        return this.$store.state['myProfile'].profile
    }
},

// then in my template, I pass this "menu" method in child component
 <LeftPanel :data="menu" />
```

This cleared that error away.  I deployed it again to firebase hosting, and voila!

Hope this bit helps you.

Comment: Pardon my being picky (I am French):  "and voilà!"

Answer (score 0):

In my case due to router name not in string:

```
:to="{name: route-name, params: {id:data.id}}"
```

change to router name in string:

```
:to="{name: 'router-name', params: {id:data.id}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to pass a hard coded text value to another component with:

```
 ChildComponent(:displayMode="formMode")
```

when it should be:

```
ChildComponent(:displayMode="'formMode'")
```

note the single quotes to indicate text instead of calling a local var inside the component.

Comment: If you want to pass String value to component then you could do it like this ```displayMode="formMode"```. *Note*: We are not binding using v-bind and therefore displayMode will store String value

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are many scenarios that can trigger this error. Here's another one which I just resolved.

I had the variable actionRequiredCount declared in the data section, but I failed to capitalize the C in Count when passing the variable as a params to a component.

Here the variable is correct:

```
data: () => {
     return{
       actionRequiredCount: ''
     }
}
```

In my template it was incorrect (notd the no caps c in "count"):

```
  <MyCustomModule :actionRequiredCount="actionRequiredcount"/>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Most people do have an error here because of:

- a typo or something that they forgot to declare/use
- the opposite, did it in several places

To avoid the typo issues, I recommend always using [Vue VSCode Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sdras.vue-vscode-snippets) so that you don't write anything by hand by rather use `vbase`, `vdata`, `vmethod` and get those parts generated for you.
Here are the ones [for Vue3](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hollowtree.vue-snippets).
You can of course also create your own snippets by doing [the following](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets).

Also make sure that you're properly writing all the correct names as [shown here](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#options-state), here is a list:

- data
- props
- computed
- methods
- watch
- emits
- expose

---

As for the second part, I usually recommend either searching the given keyword in your codebase. So like <kbd>cmd + f</kbd> + `changeSetting` in OP's case to see if it's missing a declaration somewhere in `data`, `methods` or alike.

Or even better, use an [ESlint configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68225547/8816585) so that you will be warned in case you have any kind of issues in your codebase.
[Here is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68880413/8816585) to achieve such setup with a Nuxt project + ESlint + Prettier for the most efficient way to prevent bad practices while still getting a fast formatting!

Answer (score 0):

One other common scenario is:

- You have a component (child) extending another component (parent)
- You have a property or a method `xyz` defined under `methods` or `computed` on the parent component.
- Your are trying to use parent's `xyz`, but your child component defines its own `methods` or `computed`

#### Sample code with the problem

```js
// PARENT COMPONENT
export default {
  computed() {
    abc() {},
    xyz() {} // <= needs to be used in child component
  },
  ...
}

// CHILD COMPONENT
export default {
  extends: myParentComponent,
  computed() {
    childProprty1() {},
    childProprty2() {}
  }
}
```

---

#### The solution

In this case you will need to redefine your `xyz` computed property under `computed`

###### Solution 1:

Redefine `xyz` and copy the code from the parent component

```js
// CHILD COMPONENT
export default {
  extends: myParentComponent,
  computed() {
    xyz() {
      // do something cool!
    },
    childProprty1() {},
    childProprty2() {}
  }
}
```

###### Solution 2

Redefine `xyz` property reusing parent component code (no code redundancy)

```js
// CHILD COMPONENT
export default {
  extends: myParentComponent,
  computed() {
    xyz() {
      return this.$parent.$options.computed.xyz
    },
    childProprty1() {},
    childProprty2() {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it happened because I wrote `method:` instead of `methods:` (plural). It's a silly mistake but it can happen :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add one more to the list.

TLDR: make sure you are making changes in the correct file

Context:
I am working in a codebase that we inherited from another company and I continued to get that error. Then I noticed there were two files with similar names: `search-bar.js` and `search-bar.vue.js`. The code in both files is Vue code. However, as soon as I moved my code into the other file everything started working as expected. Silly, I know, but still something worth calling out.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I had child component called from parent like this:

```
<bSearch></bSearch>
```

When I have changed to:

```
<bSearch/>
```

**Vue warn**, which was mentioned in this issue, then disappeared. I am using Vue 3 - composition API in Single file component (SFC). Hope someone will help it.

Comment: @Robert please, read carefully. This is not a question, but possible solution, which could someone help in the future :) I did not ask for a help. Here is also a lot of other possible solutions, which for instance, did not work for me.

Comment: @Robert I do not know, why you have chosen only my post. Here are a lot of other posts, which are not very related to the original question. I had the same Vue warn (mentioned in my post), when this warn is occurring. I wrote my solution. I wrote my vue configuration. So, it is clear. As I see, you did not contribute to the original question with any solution. So, please don't bother us with not helping comments. This is my last comment to this nonsene discussion. Have a nice day.