# Property or method "handleSelect" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: typescript, vue.js, element-ui

I'm using the [Element-UI component NavMenu](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/menu#navmenu) in order to create a nav bar in my web application. I'm using Vue.JS + TypeScript.

So I've created a Vue component in a folder "navBar", inside it I've:

The component `navBar.vue`:

```
<template src="./navBar.html">
</template>
<script src="./navBar.ts" lang="ts">
</script>
```

The html `navBar.html`:

```
<div id="navbar">
  <el-menu
    mode="horizontal"
    :select="handleSelect"
    background-color="rgba(95, 75, 139, 1)"
    text-color="#fff"
    active-text-color="rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)">
    <el-menu-item index="1">Item 1</el-menu-item>
  </el-menu>
</div>
```

And the TypeScript `navBar.ts`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

export default class NavBar extends Vue {

  handleSelect (key: string, keyPath: string) {
    console.log(key, keyPath)
  }

}
```

But when I click on the *"Item 1"* I get the error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "handleSelect" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
```

I can't explain why, any idea?

I've already seen other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908525/vue-warn-property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-dur) but no one used TypeScript.

Comment: What gets generated as the JavaScript from `navBar.ts`? Is `handleSelect` in the `methods`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't using the `@Component` decorator, so the `NavBar` class probably isn't setting the methods for the `Vue` instance correctly.

Add the decorator before the class definition:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Component from 'vue-class-component'

@Component
export default class NavBar extends Vue {

  handleSelect (key: string, keyPath: string) {
    console.log(key, keyPath)
  }

}
```

[Here's the GitHub repo's README for the `vue-class-component` module.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-class-component)

Comment: Thanks, I also needed to change `:select="handleSelect"` to `@select="handleSelect"`, now it works correctly.