# [Vue warn]:Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: vue.js

```html
<div class="input-wrapper" id="name" :data-text="name" :class="{ error: error.isErrorName }">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name…" @input="inputName($event.target.value)">
</div>
```

```javascript
data () {
    return {
        name:'',
        error:{
            isErrorName:false,
            isErrorEmail:false,
            isErrorSubject:false,
            isErrorMessage:false
        },
    }
},

methods:{
    inputName(val){
        this.name=val;
        this.error.isErrorName = !val.trim();
    }
}
```

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

Comment: Please, highlight your question.

Comment: Where is your `index` in the code? You are probably pasting even the wrong part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to avoid that warning, for the explanation of what's going on behind the scenes [see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908525/vue-warn-property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-dur).

And to remove the warning in your case, try it out like follows:

**HTML template**

Use `v-model` for passing the variable to the method and remove `($event.target.value)` and `@input` for being concise (See [Using-v-model-on-Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components)). For instance you bind it to the data property `name` and if you want to run that `inputName` method everytime a key is pressed by the user:

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name…" v-model="name" @keyup="inputName">
```

**Script**

Then, you do not need to add it as a parameter for the

```
methods: {
  inputName(){
    // this.name=val;
    this.error.isErrorName = !(this.name.trim());
  }
}
```

*P.S:* I tried to read your mind, if you have a more obvious goal. Please share it in the question ;)

Comment: <input type="text" v-model="name" name="name" placeholder="Name…" @keyup="inputName">                                                                                                                    inputName(){
      this.error.isErrorName = !(this.name.trim());
    }                                                                                                                 Property or method "index" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components. P.S: you are Baba Vanga)))