# Components Events: Property or method "updatebalance" is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, json, laravel, vuejs2

I use Laravel. There are 2 Vue components that are exchanged via the event bus. **"Order.vue"** and **"Balance_Label.vue"**.
When I click on the **"Order"** button, the Balance is reduced by the order amount, and the balance label is updated immediately (via Axios).
The interaction between these two components is realized via the **Event Bus** and works well.
But after updating the page I see such 2 warnings at Console:

**[Vue warn]: Property or method "updatebalance" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.
found in Root)**

**[Vue warn]: Invalid handler for event "updbalance": got undefined
found in
--->  at resources/assets/js/components/Balance_label.vue
Root**

I would not pay attention to these warnings, since everything works as it should, but after the command:
**npm run production**
there is an error:

```
**ReferenceError: updatebalance is not defined
    at dn.eval (eval at Ca (app.js:1), <anonymous>:3:465)
    at dn.t._render (app.js:1)
    at dn.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at Ie.get (app.js:1)
    at new Ie (app.js:1)
    at app.js:1
    at dn.$mount (app.js:1)
    at dn.$mount (app.js:1)
    at dn.t._init (app.js:1)
    at new dn (app.js:1)**
```

and on the page I see only the background, but there are no components...

Friends, help please! I googled for 3 days, but to no avail.
Tried all sorts of solutions, but the error remains the same.

The **"balance label"** is rendered like this:

```
<balancelabel @updbalance="updatebalance"></balancelabel>
```

The **"Order" button** rendered like this:

```
<order
           :product={{ $product->id }}
           :ordered={{ $product->ordered() ? 'true' : 'false' }}
           productname= "<b>{{ $product->name }}</b>"
></order>
```

###### **Balance_label.vue**

```
<template> 
        <label id="balance_view" class="btn btn-default tp-icon chat-icon">
                    {{ balance }}  dollars     
        </label>
</template> 

<script>
    import { bus } from '../bootstrap';
    import 'vuejs-noty/dist/vuejs-noty.css'
    export default {
        
        data: function () {
            return {
                balance: 0
            }    
        },
        
        created(){
            bus.$on('updbalance', (data) => {
               this.updatebalance(); 
            });
        },
        mounted : function() {
           
            this.updatebalance();
        
        },
        
       methods: {
           
            updatebalance: function (){

            axios
                .get('/api/v1/balance')
                .then(response => {
                    this.balance = response.data.data[0][0]
                })        
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
             },
            
        }
    };
</script>
```

###### **Order.vue**

```
<template> 
        <span>
            <button v-if="isOrdered" 
                @click.prevent="unOrder(product)" 
                type="button" 
                class="btn btn-block btn-warning btn-xs" 
                name="order-button">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart"></i>&nbsp; Cancel Order
            </button>
            <button v-else-if="!isOrdered" 
                @click.prevent="order(product)" 
                type="button" 
                class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-xs" 
                name="order-button">
                    <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>&nbsp; Order
            </button>
       </span>    
 </template> 

<script>
    import { bus } from '../bootstrap';
    import 'vuejs-noty/dist/vuejs-noty.css'
    export default {
        props: ["product", "ordered", "productname", "resp"],
        
        data: function() {
            return { 
                isOrdered: '',
            }
        },
        
        mounted() {
            this.isOrdered = this.isOrder ? true : false;
        },
        computed: {
            isOrder() {
                return this.ordered;
            },
         },
        methods: {
            
            order(product) {
            axios
                .post('/order/' + product)
                .then(response => {this.isOrdered = true;
                                   this.$noty.success("The product " + this.productname + " is Ordered!");
                                   bus.$emit('updbalance'); //send update balance event
                                   })
               .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
            },
            
            unOrder(product) {
             axios
                .post('/unorder/' + product)
                .then(response => {this.isOrdered = false;
                                   this.$noty.warning("The product order " + this.productname + " cancelled"); 
                                   bus.$emit('updbalance'); //send update balance event
                                   })
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
            }
         }
    };
</script>
```

###### **app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');

Vue.component('order', require('./components/Order.vue'));
Vue.component('balancelabel', require('./components/Balance_label.vue'));

app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

###### **bootstrap.js**

```
window._ = require('lodash');
try {
      require('bootstrap-sass');
} catch (e) {}

window.axios = require('axios');
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}

window.Vue = require('vue');
window.events = new Vue();

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueNoty from 'vuejs-noty'

//connect event bus
export const bus = new Vue();

Vue.use(VueNoty)
```

###### **package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.16"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "noty": "^3.2.0-beta",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
    "vuejs-noty": "^0.1.3"
  }
}
```

P.S.: without a bus, too, received the same warning, so there is no bus - it does not matter

I found [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908525/vue-warn-property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-dur) but it doesnt help...

**what I tried to do to resolve problem:**

- declare the method in the root element of the vue (**app.js** file),
- declare a method in the event bus (**boostrap.js** file)
- declare the method in the **order.vue**

but the error does not go away... help please...

I read many topics at stackoveflow: all of them about properties, but not about methods...

Comment: Why are you trying to pass `updatebalance` as an event when you declare the method in **Balance_label.vue**? What happens if you remove `@updbalance="updatebalance"` ?

Comment: I pass updatebalance coz the balance label emit the event from Order button. And when Order button clicked - "updbalance" event on. Then balance recieve this event and update the balance label (reduce balance amount). 
If I remove "updatebalance" all algorithm stop working. And the label will stop updating after clicking the Order button

Comment: ok, problem solved, I removed @updbalance="updatebalance".
Can you post your comment  as Answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to pass updatebalance as an event when you declare the method in Balance_label.vue? What happens if you remove @updbalance="updatebalance"