# define vue application in blade component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

I have navigation component reused in multiple blade pages with some modification. so I used:

```
<script>
    window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#navigation',
        ....
    });
</script>
```

in my navigation component.

when I included it in profile component that have:

```
<script>
    window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        ....
    });
</script>
```

one of them doesn't work. I know that these two definitions have anastomosis but I don't know how resolve it.

In simple what the matter with this:

```
<script>
    window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app1',
        ....
    });
</script>

<script>
    window.app = new Vue({
        el: '#app2',
        ....
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't have two Vue apps bound to the same element, and you can't have two Vue apps both as `window.app`.

Comment: really? no way???

Comment: Of course not. `window.app = 1; window.app = 2;` What does `window.app` equal?

Comment: I use const app1 and const app1 too, But nothing change, Is that different form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one Vue app declaration by HTML container. You can't use one declared component inside other declared component.

So you can do this.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      .....
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- MAYBE YOU CAN DO A BLADE TEMPLATE -->
        <div id="navitagion"></div>  
        <div id="app"></div>  
        <!--=============== scripts  ===============-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('path/to/vue.js')}}"></script>
        const app = new Vue({
           el: '#app',
        });
        const navigation = new Vue({
           el: '#navigation',
        });
    </body>
</html>
```

You can add references in any container to use outside of Vue declaration like javascript or in other Vue component

But try and let me know how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

you can only have one vue.js library loaded in a single HTML tag

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  .....
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">            
    </div>  
    <!--=============== scripts  ===============-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('path/to/vue.js')}}"></script>
    const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    });
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not true. You can have more than one Vue instance on a page. They do have to be bound to different elements, though. See https://codingexplained.com/coding/front-end/vue-js/using-multiple-vue-instances-page

Comment: @ceejayoz updated the question, guess enligh save the day, can you please undo what you did to my answer ? :-) english saved the day.