# Vue-Laravel form Submission

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have a form created in vue and added to a blade page.

app.js

```js
new Vue({
    router,
    components: {
        'advice-form': AdviceForm,
    }
}).$mount('#app');
```

blade.php

```php
<div class="my-6">
    <advice-form></advice-form>
</div>
```

AdviceForm Component

```html
<template>
  <input
    class="md:w-auto w-full"
    type="text"
    name="name"
    id="name"
    placeholder="Full name"
    v-model="name"
/>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "AdviceForm",
    methods: {
      data() {
        return {
          name: ''
        };
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

When I try to add v-model for inputs I get an error saying `Property or method "name" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.` I am sure the `name` is defined in the data property. Also, the `<advice-form></advice-form>` is placed within the #app div in blade page.

Can anyone help me figure out what is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the "name" is there in data field of AdviceForm component?

Comment: @Piyush yes sir sure.

Comment: In that case we need a working demo to check it...

Comment: Have you looked at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908525/vue-warn-property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-dur

Comment: Did you try changing `name` to `form_name`?

Comment: Why you are using data inside methods? You should put it along with methods, not inside methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your script to the following and try not to use any reserved keywords.

```
new Vue({
    router,
    components: [AdviceForm],
}).$mount('#app');

<script>
  export default {
    name: "AdviceForm",
    // data should be function outside the 
    // methods and try a non reserved keyword.
    data: function() {
      return {
        form_name: ''
      };
    },
    methods: {
       // All the methods
    },
    components: []
  };
</script>
```

Comment: It was a mistake that I couldn't have found without someone else looking at my code. Thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 0):

I don't see full code base for AdviceForm but surely, issue is pointing out that name property is not defined and vue can't find that property.

Something like this below

new Vue({
  data: {
    name: 'name'
  }
}).$mount('#app');

---

@Tes3awy I think this can be problem.
Please declare data function inside Vue class.

```
new Vue({
    router,
    components: {
        'advice-form': AdviceForm,
    },
   data() {
        return {
          name: ''
        };
     }

}).$mount('#app');
```

Comment: Can you add below data function?

<script>
  export default {
    name: "AdviceForm",
    data() {
        return {
          name: ''
        };
     }
    
  };
</script>

Comment: Yes. Please try to remove methods property only and declare data function only.

Comment: @Tes3awy Please check updated answer and try decare data function in app.js.

Comment: I doubt this. The Vue instance is the parent component and it uses a child component `AdviceForm`. `AdviceForm` should take care of itself, and the `data` should be on `AdviceForm` only.