# Can't access data property from parent in slot child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two components rad-list and rad-card, I placed a slot element in rad-list where I will place rad-card, now rad-card receices an object from computedResults array (in parent scope) and iterates through them and pass result to item prop in rad-card, but since computedResults is defined in parent component my rad-card  instance doesn't have access to it?

```
<rad-list model="Discount" module="Discount" results="discounts">
        <rad-card :item="result" v-for="result in computedResults" :key="result.id" :model="module"></rad-card>
    </rad-list>
```

I get following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "computedResults" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

(found in <Root>)
```

My rad-list component:

```
<template>
<div class="RADlist_maincontainer">
    <layout-pagination-1 v-show="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" @paginate="paginate({ page:pagination.current_page, paginate:paginate })"></layout-pagination-1>
    <div class="RADlist_wrapper">
        <!--rad-card, or any other component which will use computedResults GOES HERE-->
        <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <layout-pagination-1 v-show="pagination.last_page > 1" :pagination="pagination" @paginate="paginate({ page:pagination.current_page, paginate:paginate })"></layout-pagination-1>
</div>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex';
export default{
name: 'RADlist',


computed:
{
    computedResults: function()
    { 
        return this.$store.state[this.module][this.results];
    },
    pagination: function()
    { 
        return this.$store.state[this.module].pagination;
    },
    ...mapState('Loader', ['loader'])
},


props:
{
    component: { default:'rad-card', type:String },
    module: { default:'Post', type:String },
    action: { default:'list', type:String },
    results: { default:'posts', type:String },
    page: { default:1, type:Number },
    paginate: { default:6, type:Number },

},


mounted()
{
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');
    this.$store.dispatch(this.module+'/'+this.action, { page: this.page, paginate: this.paginate, loaderId:2473});
},


}
</script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Vue warn\]: Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908525/vue-warn-property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-dur)

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter if computed or not you can send data to the child but in the child, you have to assign props in the component first if you did that move you have to check the output of the "computedResults" is like the way you want it.