# How to setup lint-staged for Vue projects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, prettier, lint-staged

I created a new Vue3 app using the Vue CLI and selected Prettier for my linter config. I want to use commitlint, husky and lint-staged to validate commit messages and lint the code before pushing it.

**What I did**

Based on https://commitlint.js.org/#/guides-local-setup I setup commitlint with husky

```
npm install --save-dev @commitlint/{cli,config-conventional}
echo "module.exports = { extends: ['@commitlint/config-conventional'] };" > commitlint.config.js

npm install husky --save-dev
npx husky install
npx husky add .husky/commit-msg 'npx --no -- commitlint --edit $1'
```

Based on https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged#installation-and-setup I setup lint-staged

```
npx mrm@2 lint-staged
```

and inside the package.json I replace

```
"lint-staged": {
  "*.js": "eslint --cache --fix"
}
```

with

```
"lint-staged": {
  "*": "npm run lint"
}
```

**The problem**

When modifying the README.md file in the project to

```
# my-repo

---

new commit
```

and try to commit that I get the following error message

```
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
[STARTED] Preparing...
[SUCCESS] Preparing...
[STARTED] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Running tasks for *
[STARTED] npm run lint
[FAILED] npm run lint [FAILED]
[SUCCESS] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Applying modifications...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up...

✖ npm run lint:

> my-repo@0.1.0 lint
> vue-cli-service lint "/home/.../my-repo/README.md"

error: Parsing error: Invalid character at README.md:1:1:
> 1 | # my-repo
    | ^
  2 |
  3 | ---
  4 |


1 error found.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/my-repo
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c lint-staged

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/.../.npm/_logs/2021-12-27T10_07_27_498Z-debug.log
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

**What it should do**

Only fix the files that have been modified. The linter knows about files it is able to fix (js, ts, vue, html, ...).

When having a modified markdown file I get no errors when opening the terminal and run `npm run lint`. But I do get errors when using lint-staged with this setup `"*": "npm run lint"`

What is the correct setup for lint-staged to lint "lintable" files only?

Comment: README.md doesn't need to be linted. ignore README.md file in .eslintignore

Comment: @AhmadKZX I think there should be a more general solution because normally `npm run lint` would not try to fix a markdown file so the problem might be somewhere else

Comment: Yeah, why are you using ESlint on a `.md` file? Apply specific linters to supported files.

Comment: @kissu I updated the last part of my question, maybe this helps

Comment: What is your `npm run lint` actually does? I'm pretty sure it is not executed at all, hence why you don't have any errors.

Comment: @kissu under the hood it will execute `vue-cli-service lint`. https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/eslint.html

Comment: Looking [at this](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/eslint.html#injected-commands), it says that it will `vue-cli-service lint will lint dotfiles .*.js by default`. Anyway, you should probably dump this and use your own ESlint configuration here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Update regarding the comments

###### Other lint-staged syntaxes

I've suggested `"**/*.{js,vue}": ["npm run lint:js:fix"]`, first of, `lint:js:fix` is subjective and up to you. This is what Kent C Dodds is using, so I'm just naming it in the same way.

But you could totally have `lint:watermelon-potato-hehe` instead, doesn't matter.

Now, about your propositions:

1. `"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "npm run lint"`, this one is targeting more extensions, which is totally fine. You may not really use `.tsx/.jsx` since it's not really popular among Vue devs.
   About `.ts` itself, it may probably work good enough (maybe you'll need to add some plugins to your ESlint configuration). I'm not into TS so I can't really help on this one but it's out of the husky/lint-staged scope anyway.
   Last time I started a Vue3 project, I've used [Vitesse](https://github.com/antfu/vitesse) which has some nice defaults with TS, this may be a good start for you maybe.

As for the second part, since I like to setup my own ESlint config, with some simple and well documented API, we're using `eslint --ext .js,.vue --fix`. That way I'm sure of what is happening and how to troubleshoot it if needed.
[vue-cli-service lint](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/eslint.html#configuration) may be a good default package aimed towards Vue with some defaults, I'm not sure what's inside it and even if it's probably just an ESlint with some baked-in configuration, again we prefer to make our own Vue configuration with vanilla ESlint.

So yeah, if you need to go fast, use `vue-cli-service lint` for some quick linting, if you want to have a better flow in your project and want to fine grain your config, use vanilla ESlint, you'll get less trouble overall IMO.

2. `"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --fix"`. On the right side, we globally have the same `lint:js:fix` scripts but with additional extensions.

So, you may ask why are we even writing the extensions on the left side for `lint-staged` and on the right side for `lint:js:fix`? I'd answer that those are not really needed on the right side (AFAIK), because lint-staged will only run the command to the left list of extensions.
Here, we wanted to be more explicit about the exact extensions we're targeting and also, it enables you to run `npm run lint:js:fix` in your CLI at any given point without getting errors on files ESlint is not handling (`.txt`, `.json`, `.md`, `.jpg` etc...).
So it could maybe be removed (not sure), fastest way to be sure is to try!

3. `"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --fix"`, this one may work fine as explained in the previous paragraph. Didn't tried it myself thought.

###### What about the other extensions?

Regarding `.html`, you should not have a lot of those in your Vue project. You could use the [W3C validator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input) to check for any errors if you really need it.
If you're speaking about your HTML in the `template` tags in your `.vue` files, those will be ESlint'ed properly. If you setup a Prettier on top of it, you will also get some nice auto-formatting which is really awesome to work with (once your team has agreed on a `.prettierrc` config).

Regarding `.json` files, those are not handled by ESlint. ESlint is only for JavaScript-ish files. If you want to lint/format your `.json` or even any other extensions at all, you can aim towards NPM, find a package that suits your team's needs and add it to your chain like `"**/*.json": ["npm run lint-my-json-please"]` and you should be good!

At the end, husky + lint-staged are not doing anything special really. They are tools to automate what you could write yourself in a CLI, so if it's working when done manually and you're happy with the result, you can put it in your config but you need to first found what the proper package and it's configuration.

---

In your `package.json`, you could have the following

```json
"scripts": {
  "lint:js": "eslint . --ext .js,.vue",
  "lint:js:fix": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --fix",
},
```

In your `.lintstagedrc`

```json
{
  "**/*.{js,vue}": ["npm run lint:js:fix"]
}
```

In `.husky/pre-commit`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run lint-staged
```

In `.husky/commit-msg`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx --no-install commitlint --edit ""
```

You can setup [ESlint to watch any errors in your files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68225547/8816585) in VScode (a lint + formatter when your files are saved is also doable pretty easily).

That way, you can run `npm run lint:js` to check the issues by yourself.
Otherwise, let husky run lint-staged and apply the `eslint --fix` to all of your `.js` and `.vue` files.

Your `commitlint.config.js` config should be okay!

---

As a reminder here, `lint:js` will scan all of your JS and Vue files.
While, when you commit and husky is executed (by running the `lint:js:fix` script), **ONLY** the files that you have touched will be linted (that's the whole point of `lint-staged`).

Comment: 1. would you mind explaining why not use `"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "npm run lint"` or `"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx --fix"` or `"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "eslint --fix"` ? 2. What about other files like .json or .html (I don't think they are picked up by the vue cli service but maybe this is possible) ?

Comment: @kissu I think `"**/*.{vue,js,jsx,ts,tsx}": "npm run lint"` is the right one to pick :)