# How to chain vite build and tests?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite, vitest

It seems that `vite build` command doesn't run tests (unit tests written with `vitest`, for example) before building the application for production. This is quite unsafe.

Is there a way to configure `vite build` to run tests before trying to build ?

I couldn't find anything in [Build Options](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you have in your `package.json`, `scripts` section? Don't you have some `test` or alike?

`build` is used to bundle your app and ship it to production. It's not supposed to run any tests by default.
You could achieve this by doing something like

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "vite build && npm run test:unit && npm run test:e2e",
  "test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom",
  "test:e2e": "start-server-and-test preview http://localhost:4173/ 'cypress open --e2e'",
},
```

If you generate a new project via the CLI, you will have most of them already written for you, then it's a matter of properly chaining them with `&&` to assure that they are all succeeding before proceeding further.

[image]

---

You can also add some Git hooks with something like [husky + lintstaged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70522812/8816585) so that your flow is using something by default before even pushing it to a remote repo.

Otherwise, it's part of your CI. Either it be a Docker compose file, some Github actions, Gitlab pipelines or anything your devops team could have setup for your deploy environments.

Comment: I needed to change the order to make it so that a failed test would stop the build process, but your example got me pointed in the right direction. This modification worked for my needs: "build": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:e2e && vite build",