# How to make VS Code give problem indicators for unused parameters?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, frontend

Is it possible to make VS Code highlight unused parameters?
I'm working on a Vue component with TypeScript if this make any difference.

It shows unused imports just fine:
[image]

but not unused properties:
[image]

I have added this to my settings.json file but it didn't help.

```
"editor.showUnused": true,
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "editorUnnecessaryCode.border": "#ff0000"
}
```

Vue component example

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { Component } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
    export default class VueComponentExample extends Vue {

    bla: boolean = false;
  
}
</script>
```

Comment: This can be achieved thanks to ESlint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68225547/8816585

Comment: I just tried 
"no-unused-vars": ["error", { "vars": "all", "args": "after-used", "ignoreRestSiblings": false }]
from the doc https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars
it got some properties but it's still not showing local component properties.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `local component properties`? Mind sharing your whole ESlint setup? Got a public github repo?

Comment: thanks for the help so far kissu ! :)
Just added a little example, and the bla property is the one I'm referring to.

the eslint file isn't that interesting it only have some indent, quotes, semi and vue/html-indent so I pretty sure nothing in here should cause this.

Comment: Not sure how it behaves with `vue-property-decorator`, but ESlint should be able to find out what is not used so far. Maybe you need something additional while using classes like there.

Answer (score 0):

Since in your tags you indicate that you are using TypeScript, you can use [the `noUnusedParameters` tsconfig setting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUnusedParameters). Quoting from the setting's docs:

> Report errors on unused parameters in functions.

Like so in the tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Or, as indicated in the comments by [@kissu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8816585), you could use ESLint. For some tips on setup, see [Vue 2 - ESLint + Standard + Prettier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68191278/11107541).