# Javascript + Vuex issue: how to access a Vuex boolean in a `v-if`

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

While working in a team project, my teammates wish me to display a `div` only when a certain boolean is true. However, I do not know how to access said boolean in the html.

---

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="store.state.initSession">If true</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from '../store'
...
</script>
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store =  new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    initSession: false,
  },
...
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Property or method "store" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.
```

The error has been discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908525/vue-warn-property-or-method-is-not-defined-on-the-instance-but-referenced-dur), but I continue not to know how to solve it.

Comment: What's `...` in a script? You need to do something there. Generally you just access a store like this.$store in Vue 2. No explicit import is needed

Comment: @EstusFlask if I do so I get the exact same error, yet with `$store` as opposed to `store`.

Comment: Probably means that you didn't use it properly, see https://v3.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/ . The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's unknown if it's so

Comment: store is only exported so it can be imported in `main.js` and added to the Vue instance.  did you do that?  accessing store in components is done with `this.$store` or different helper imports

Comment: Imports are readily available in template only when using `<script setup>`. In all other cases, they need to be made available. Your question will remain unanswerable until you disclose what `...` stands for inside `<script>`. There are many ways in which you can expose something to the component's template (`return` from `setup` function, using the Option API, declaring as global, etc...), but they vary based on component API used, vue version, etc... I suggest glancing over the examples available in Vue documentation first.